# Save user ID in JSON file

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

Today I'm trying to make a json data to link discord account to another account (League of Legends, Dota, etc...)

To make my database, I'm using this code:

```js
message.reply(`Your account is link to **${args[1]}**`).then(msg => {
  msg.delete({
    timeout: 5000
  });
});

userID = message.author;

let link = require('../link.json')

link.userID = {
  name: `${message.author.username}`,
  lol: `${args[1]}`,
}

var string = JSON.stringify(link, null, '\t');

fs.writeFile('./link.json', string, function(err) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
})
```

If bob writes `/link lol boby02` and I (StarKleey 帅哥) write `/link lol StarKleey` the json will be:

```
{
    "userID": {                     //here I would like "@<565465478767545>": {
        "name": "bob",
        "lol": "boby02"
    },
    "userID": {                     //and here          "@<456465574385735>": {
        "name": "StarKleey 帅哥",
        "lol": "StarKleey"
    }
}
```

How can I do that?
This is what I'm currently using:

```js
link.message.author = {
  name: `${message.author.username}`,
  lol: `${args[1]}`,
}
```

Reload :

```
{
    "@<565465478767545>": {
        "name": "bob",
        "lol": "boby02"
    },
    "@<456465574385735>": {
        "name": "StarKleey 帅哥",
        "lol": "StarKleey"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use JSON files for a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently storing the username, while you seem to want to store the user id: you should try using [`User.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id):

```js
link.message.author = {
  name: `${message.author.id}`,
  lol: `${args[1]}`,
}
```

Comment: I know I use username and it's done on purpose but me I would like the userID to be like in my reload

Comment: But I will probably try to make a database with something else

Comment: @StarKleey If you want to store the mention you can, but it's less efficient in my opinion. Anyway, if you want to store that just add `<@` at the beginning and `>` at the end.